# finding pixel coordinates

Tags: 3d

I'm trying to calculate pixel coordinates of 3d points Xw = [150 200 350]

where R is given as

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

K is give as

\begin{bmatrix}
    -70\\
    -95\\
    -120\\
\end{bmatrix}

and ox and oy is 320x240. I'm using opencv 3.0 to do this and I get [533, 520] as an output. However, when I do manual calculation on paper, I got [493,465]. This is homework question. So I'm not looking for solution.I just want to know which one is the wrong one so that I can isolate the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Are we expected to know what do you mean by R and K?

Comment: Sorry if my question is vague. The question is to find pixel coordinates on image plane of pinhole camera that corresponds to 3d point in the world.  R is rotation vector, K is location of camera.